# How can I reduce loading effect in dc common drain source follower?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, buffer, source-follower

I want to make a dc voltage buffer using an nmos source follower. I found that by making Rs as large as possible or even open, Vs= Vgs-Vth. I verified it using multisim. The problem is it suffers from loading effects. I wanted to make a dc voltage buffer using the least amount of transistors.[image]

Comment: Use a BJT for much better input-output conformance and make sure it is properly biased.

Comment: Why use a W=L=100u? Have you tried a much larger W/L ratio?

Comment: This won’t do what you expect

Comment: @Tony EE rocketscientist   Why? I've seen this used in research articles to read out the floating gate voltage of a mosfet

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hq2x.jpg  at (b) you can see the floating gate is read by the source follower.  Here's a link to the full document: https://tohoku.repo.nii.ac.jp/index.php?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_action_common_download&item_id=53595&item_no=1&attribute_id=18&file_no=1&page_id=33&block_id=38

Comment: Yes but you stated none of those details in your question